# Java security exception with Apache CXF in weblogic not finding provider: ApacheXMLDSig

Tags: apache, weblogic, cxf, ws-security, bpmn

I have a BPMN composite application deployed in weblogic. I have a web service deployed as an ear in the same weblogic server. Both (composite application and web service) use security policies. The BPMN app calls the web service and it passes the security header to the service. The service is deployed as an ear, built using Apache CXF and Spring. When I call the web service directly (with SoapUI) it responds correctly.

When I call the BPMN process, it fails, writting these logs in my CXF Service log file:

```
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@1ac341ec was created. Current flow:
  receive [PolicyInInterceptor, AttachmentInInterceptor]
  pre-stream [CertConstraintsInterceptor]
  post-stream [StaxInInterceptor]
  read [SAAJPreInInterceptor, WSDLGetInterceptor, ReadHeadersInterceptor, SoapActionInInterceptor, StartBodyInterceptor]
.
.
.      .
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.StartBodyInterceptor@1a7ee16a
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor@1a4f6525
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor  ==> WSS4JInInterceptor: enter handleMessage()
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig  ==> Cannot find DOM mechanism type
javax.xml.crypto.NoSuchMechanismException: Cannot find DOM mechanism type
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:207)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SAMLTokenProcessor.<init>(SAMLTokenProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getProcessor(WSSConfig.java:835)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:400)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:287)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:207)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for XMLSignatureFactory(provider: ApacheXMLDSig)cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1268)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1220)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:202)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1262)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
    ... 38 more
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for XMLSignatureFactory(provider: ApacheXMLDSig)cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1268)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1220)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:202)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SAMLTokenProcessor.<init>(SAMLTokenProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getProcessor(WSSConfig.java:835)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:400)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:287)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:207)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1262)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
    ... 38 more
2015-05-26 10:13:01 WARN  org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor  ==> 
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (Unable to load class org.apache.ws.security.processor.SAMLTokenProcessor)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getProcessor(WSSConfig.java:840)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:400)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:287)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:207)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.NoSuchMechanismException: Cannot find DOM mechanism type
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:207)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SAMLTokenProcessor.<init>(SAMLTokenProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getProcessor(WSSConfig.java:835)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for XMLSignatureFactory(provider: ApacheXMLDSig)cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1268)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1220)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:202)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1262)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
    ... 38 more
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor@1a4f6525
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.StartBodyInterceptor@1a7ee16a
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapActionInInterceptor@1a7ee09e
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor@1a7ee159
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor@1f97be0e
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor$SAAJPreInInterceptor@19d1ad38
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor@1a7ee090
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@18d6bcfc
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor@1a7ee082
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@1ee1bab8
2015-05-26 10:13:01 WARN  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Interceptor for {http://citi.cu/sip/criminal/process/CriminalCaseService}CriminalCaseService#{http://citi.cu/sip/criminal/process/CriminalCaseService}FindExpertCriminalCase has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header.
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:846)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (Unable to load class org.apache.ws.security.processor.SAMLTokenProcessor)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getProcessor(WSSConfig.java:840)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:400)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:287)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:207)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.NoSuchMechanismException: Cannot find DOM mechanism type
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:207)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SAMLTokenProcessor.<init>(SAMLTokenProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getProcessor(WSSConfig.java:835)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for XMLSignatureFactory(provider: ApacheXMLDSig)cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1268)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1220)
    at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:202)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1262)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
    ... 38 more
2015-05-26 10:13:01 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  ==> Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor@1ee1bac4 to phase setup
```

There is some kind of trouble with the jars I can't understand. This is the content of the file weblogic-application.xml, inside META-INF/weblogic-application.xml of the ear file:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application">
    <application-param>
        <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </application-param>

    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.hibernate.ejb.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
        <package-name>cu.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.wsdl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.xml.crypto.dsig.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.xml.crypto.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.jcp.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.xalan.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.xml.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.wml.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.html.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.xpath.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.regexp.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.bcel.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.cxf.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.ws.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.hsqldb.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

Comment: What version of java and weblogic?

Comment: Weblogic: 10.3, Java 1.6.0_45-b06

Comment: Did you find any solution meanwhile? We are facing a similar problem on WebSphere :(

Comment: No, I haven't found any solution so far. Still no idea of the problem.

Comment: What version of cxf, wss4j and xmlsec libraries?

Comment: Solved using your configuration of `<prefer-application-packages>` and removing `<package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>`

Answer (score 0):

I copied xmlsec.jar in jre/lib/ext directory and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

we use (regarding technology) more or less the same stuff,

I got the same stacktrace when trying to address the cxf part of the application and (in our case) this is solved by using a 64 bit jvm in stead of a 32 one (client side);

hope it helps someone...

S.